# How to Parse file Using Delimiter scanner

Tags: java

I am using Java Scanner class to delimit a String

Here is my string

```
%22locations%22:[{%22linkId%22:21737516,%22latLng%22:{%22lat%22:12.9219,%22lng%22:77.56022},%22type%22:%22s%22},

{%22linkId%22:21741609,%22latLng%22:{%22lat%22:12.921509,%22lng%22:77.49382},%22type%22:%22s%22},

{%22linkId%22:18632091,%22latLng%22:{%22lat%22:12.904157,%22lng%22:77.470489},%22type%22:%22v%22},

{%22linkId%22:76684742,%22latLng%22:{%22lat%22:12.88959,%22lng%22:77.45314},%22type%22:%22s%22}
```

I want Output as

```
locations:[{latLng:{lat:12.9219,lng:77.56022},type:'s'},

{latLng:{lat:12.921509,lng:77.49382},type:'s'},

{latLng:{lat:12.904157,lng:77.470489},type:'v'},

{latLng:{lat:12.88959,lng:77.45314},type:'s'}
]
```

here is my code

```
s.useDelimiter("%22|linkId:\\d+,");
```

I am not able to remove `linkid:integer` and add single quotes around `type` value, e.g. `'s'` instead of `s`.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `Scanner`, just use `String.replaceAll`:

First remove all `%22`,
then remove all `linkId:...`,
finally add quotes around type value:

```
 String output = input.replaceAll("%22", "")
                      .replaceAll("linkId:\\d+,", "")
                      .replaceAll("type:(.)", "type:'$1'");
```

Comment: Ok! how to do with java scanner Delimiter,I am using file's                                       s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Code1.txt")));
            PrintWriter outfile=new PrintWriter("MyFile.txt");
            s.useDelimiter("%22|:\\d+,|linkId");
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                outfile.print(s.next());
                
            }
            outfile.close();

Comment: Scanner is to "parse" or tokenize strings. Your question was "I want output as ...": for that you can't use Scanner and my answer is what you need. If your question is "how can I find certain values in this JSON message", then that's quite a different question. I recommend you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Note that you need to `replaceAll("%22", "\"")` to make this "useful" JSON.

Comment: Yeah But ,Now I am reading from simple text file & writing to other text file ,Am not using any JSON

Comment: the content of your simple text file is JSON. It's a text format like XML.

Answer (score 0):

Your delimiter can't accept `linkId:\\d+` because your string doesn't contain continues data like `linkId:21741609` but `linkId%22:21741609`.

So you need to use

```
s.useDelimiter("%22|linkId%22:\\d+,");
```

But changing `s` to `'s'` is impossible with Scanner, because Scanner can be used only to read (or skip some) data, not to add it. Your best solution would be to read your entire string and then change its content something like `.replaceAll("type:(\\w)", "type:'$1'")` as [mentioned by @geert3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27720134/1393766).

Comment: No I am using File parsing mechanism not related to any URL

Comment: @Rakesh I updated my answer. But it just looks like you are using wrong tools to solve your problem. Maybe consider adding more informations about what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: Yup got it thanks!! I have to go for string reaplcement,But How can replace String using files??

Comment: Your scanner will read your data in chunks split on `%22` so `next` will never return at the same time `type:c` because `%22type%22:%22s%22` will be split into `type` `:` and `s` so `s.next().replaceAll(...)` can't be used here. Instead read entire content of file first and store it in one string with skipping things you don't want (use StringBuilder and its append here, not concatenation of Strings). Then you can use replaceAll on that string. After replacement is done you can write such string into file (while replacing remember that Strings are immutable).

Comment: ,Thank you !! I got the out put by Reading entire File into a String..